# How can I check whether such a element is exists in the HTML which is exists it the anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a URL plus a anchor in the end of that, something like this:

```
www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg#idname
```

Now I want to know, is there any element in the HTML which has `id="idname"`? How can I do that?

Comment: `if ( $('#idname').length )`

Comment: [***How do I test whether an element exists?***](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/)

Comment: @adeneo Oh, I'm impressed, short, simple and correct. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also parse with vanilla JS

```
var raw = www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg#idname;
var exists = false;
try {
    var arrRaw = raw.split('#');
    if (arrRaw[1]) {
       if ( arrRaw[1] === 'idname') { exists = true}
    } else {
      exists = false;
    }       
} catch (error) {
    exists = false;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#idname').length){
   //it exists
} else
{
   //it doesn't
}
```